# A question about root subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be two linear operators on a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $n$.

Prove that if the composition of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commutes, then the root subspaces of $\sigma$ are invariant subspaces of $\tau$.

I tried to explain this by block matrix because the matrix $A$ of $\sigma$ can be quasi-diagonal under appropriate basis (I have not learned that any complex square matrix is similar to a Jordan Form), and we can also divide the matrix B of $\tau$ into the same block form as A. Like:

$B=$$\begin{bmatrix} B_1&B_{12}&\cdots&B_{1t}\\B_{21}&B_2&\cdots&B_{2t}\\\vdots&\vdots& &\vdots\\B_{t1}&B_{t2}&\cdots&B_t
\end{bmatrix}$

and $A=diag(A_1,A_2,...,A_t)$. But I failed to verify that if $A_iB_{ij}=B_{ij}A_j$, then $B_{ij}=0$, which is necessary if $\sigma$'s root subspaces are invariant subspaces of $\tau$.

Comment: Please do not write your title in all caps, it is regarded as shouting and is not polite.

Comment: I've never before heard of a *root subspace* in a context like this. Can you tell us where you found the term and what it means? The person who answered your question is treating it as the eigenspace, which certainly is a plausible interpretation.

Comment: @TedShifrin From other posts it seems that "root space" does not refer to eigenspaces as I presumed. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3730048/741526 Rather it seems to refer to generalized eigenspaces